# Asp.core 2, не могу получить Claims из httpcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Через di получаю объект IHttpContextAccessor в контроллере

```
public string GetEmailCurrentUser()
            {
                return _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Claims
                    .FirstOrDefault(el => el.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")?.Value;
            }
```

Раньше в asp.core 1, я мог получить email используя такую конструкцию, после миграции на asp.core 2 я просто получаю null

В чем может быть дело? Может направите куда копать?

Comment: А почему бы не брать по имени клайма?

Comment: попробуйте `ClaimTypes.Email` подробнее [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)