# asp.core2 получить claims пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, jwt

В asp.core 1 я могу получить claims текущего залогиненного пользователя, через JWT, используя HttpContextAccessor и DI

Например:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
        {
            private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

            public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
            {           
                _httpContext = httpContext;
            }
        }
```

В asp.core 2 это уже не работает. _httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
 равен false, и просто не содержит claims.
При том, если обратно мигрировать на asp.core 1, то всё прекрасно работает.

Я узнал что в asp.core 2 нужно явно прописывать

```
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Но это не помогает я не могу получить claims

Вот мой код startup.cs из проекта asp.core 2

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ...
                };
            });

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

Есть ли возможность получить claims залогиненного пользователя?

Comment: Этот вопрос чем то отличается от вашего предыдущего?

Comment: Вы об этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743162/asp-core-2-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-claims-%D0%B8%D0%B7-httpcontext ?

Comment: Ага, я не понял, чем там кончилось и в чем отличие от этого вопроса

Comment: Я думал русская версия сайта и англоязычная это обособленные друг от друга площадки и вопросы могут повторяться, чтобы повысить вероятность получения ответа

Comment: Так оба ваших вопроса в русскоязычной части. Англоязычная тут https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: О, прошу прощения. Я тогда тот удалю